# Humorous story about toilet paper perforations leading to the creation "Nothing" - an unbreakable, invisible material

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

In this short story, a scientist/engineer discovers that the perforations on toilet paper are the strongest part.  He reasons that more perforations will make it even stronger.  He makes a material that is so perforated that it consists of nearly nothing (hence the name, "Nothing"), and is invisible and impenetrable.

Comment: So... We reopen this question, copy the answer from that question to here, make that the accepted answer, and then close the original again as a duplicate?

Comment: @TGnat We reopen, and then we wait until the OP here has acknowledged that that is the answer.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, can you repost your answer from [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95453/story-about-a-man-who-discovers-the-power-of-nothing/95456#95456)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["It Was Nothing—Really!"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45045) by Theodore Sturgeon. See Sean Duggan's answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95453/story-about-a-man-who-discovers-the-power-of-nothing).